# Make nav underline animate based on class

Tags: html, css

I have a `.nav-link`

When `.active` is added to it, it gets `text-decoration: underline`. How do i make this text decoration animate by sliding in from the left?

Comment: Can you provide some code or a jsfiddle link to what you have so far?

Comment: you can't animate `text-decoration: underline`, create a custom underline by using `::before` or `::after`...

Answer (score 0):

You can create and animate custom underline like this. As you cannot animate the text-decordation: underline;

```
.nav-link:after{
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      width: 0; height: 3px;
      display: block;
      margin-top: 5px;
      right: 0;
      background: #fff;
      transition: width .2s ease; // this will add animation from left to right.
      -webkit-transition: width .2s ease;
    }

.nav-link:active:after{
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: #fff;
}
```